# Send a redirect from server to Angular

Tags: java, angular

Trying to send a response.sendRedirect to an HTML page on my server But, the function on Angular side always trying to parse my HTML page to JSON. even though my I'm configuring my Observable generic to 'any'.
Looked *everywhere* couldn't find an answer.
Thank you everyone who tries to help.

```
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getSession().invalidate();
        String loginUrl = new Gson().toJson("login.html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        out.print(loginUrl);
        out.flush();
    }
public logOut():Observable<any> {
    return this.client.get<any>("../Login");
  }



 public disconnect():void {
    this.service.logOut().subscribe( content => {   
    }, fail => {
      console.log(fail);
    });
```

Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/...

Comment: The reason this isn't working is because you're sending an API request and that request itself is the one getting redirected. If you want your browser to get redirected you would have to return an Object (JSON or String) back via the API and then your `logOut` method (or whatever is subscribing to it) should handle the redirect.

Comment: Tried to send the URL as String object still got the same error. When tried to send the URL as JSON got that error = %22login.html%22. Angular parsing the "" of the URL so it can't find the page to redirect me to.

Comment: Were you sending it as a `200 OK` or still as a `30X Redirect`?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand the question. I'm sending it as you see in the doGet method nothing more nothing less. In my HttpErrorResponse i see in 'statusText'=OK.

Comment: Ah, you're still using the `sendRedirect` method then? You need to change it to send the redirect URL as a standard 'success' response. See section 5 of https://www.baeldung.com/servlet-json-response

Comment: Changed the API exactly as stated in section 5. I don't get any error but nothing happens when I invoke 'disconnect'. Check the API in debug mode, don't know if it sent properly but no exception or something all the lines works. Updated the 'doGet method to show you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not a JAVA API developer so there may be a more efficient way of doing the JAVA backend.

Okay, in order to get this to work you should update your code to be the following:

**Backend:**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getSession().invalidate();
    String loginUrl = "index.html";
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    out.print(loginUrl);
    out.flush();
}
```

**Angular:**

```
public logOut():Observable<string> {
    return this.client.get<string>("../Login");
}

public disconnect():void {
    this.service.logOut().subscribe(redirectUrl => {
        const baseUrl = window.location.href.split('/').slice(0,4).join('/');
        window.location.href = `${baseUrl}/${redirectUrl}`;
    }, fail => {
        // Do fail stuff
    });
}
```

Update: Changed the redirect location based off of the comments.

IMO this solution is starting to get a bit dirty. It will work in a pinch but, in the long-run, I would recommend changing to a Angular-routing related solution similar to the solution posted by '[Thomas Cayne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57246322/5487673)'

Comment: Tried it but I get in my path = "http://localhost:8080/login.html". Angular redirect me to the server name/login.html. I need it to redirect to me to servername/projectname/login.html. In my example it should be="http://localhost:8080/Project_Basic_Java_Phase_2/login.html/                                    Only need to add to the url my project name and it works perfectly.

Comment: Well what should the path be?

Comment: Edited the comment. Thank you so much for helping me btw. I'm really stuck with no one to ask.

Comment: Thank you man it worked. Really appreciate it. If there's a way I can help you to just ask. Thank you so much man.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Mizrahi: do not send `login.html` back from the server. Send back something like this: `'{"redirectTo": "login"}'`.

First you need to import the angular router in your service:

```
import {Route} from "@angular/router"
```

Then inject it in your component constructor:

```
constructor(private route: Route) { }
```

Finally in your `disconnect()` method:

```
public disconnect():void {
    this.service.logOut().subscribe( content => {
         this.route.navigate([`/${content.redirectTo}`])
    }, fail => console.log('Display fail error:', fail)
  )
);
```

Also, `disconnect()` method might not be necessary because you can do the work from:

```
  logOut(): Observable<any> {
    return this.client.get<any>('../Login')
      .pipe(
        map(success => this.route.navigate([`/${success}`]),
        catchError(fail => console.log('Display fail error:', fail)
        // and then redirect somewhere
        )
      )
  }
```